# React Native weird flex behavior

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a header with an image so I write this:

```
  <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          padding: 20
          }}
  >
    <View style={{ flex: 3 }}>
      <Image
        source={this.images.header}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignSelf: "flex-end",    // HERE
          resizeMode: "contain",
          marginTop: -20,
          marginLeft: -20
        }}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
```

The weird part is `alignSelf: "flex-end"` - this align the image at the left side! As far as I know, it must be `alignSelf: "flex-start"` to align left.

Am I wrong?

PS: I use `marginTop: -20` and `marginLeft: -20` to stick the image to borders of the device (because of `padding: 20` the container)

Any idea?

> Thank in advance!

Comment: remove  resizeMode: "contain"

Comment: @KamleshGupta Then the image is so big!

Comment: can you please try with flex: -1

Comment: I checked it is working with me.

Comment: I use `style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: "center" }}` for image - the left part of image is cutted... but somehow working

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the `Image` cover the whole space but the image data is resized so that you think it is only in a part of the view. Try removing `flex: 1`and set the `width`and `height`properly or at leaset one of both.

Comment: I want it to be responsive, can I use width then (and avoid `flex`?)

Comment: Yeah! You can but with just one both to let the screen adjust.